# Many To Many Relationship 3 Models Laravel [5.6]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I've 3 models in my app **Company**, **User**, **Role**

The business rule is like this:

- **User** is **Role** at **Company**
- **Elon** is **CEO** at **SpaceX**
- **Cindy** is **Manager** at **SpaceX**
- **Elon** is **CEO** at **Tesla**

I'm thinking about creating a 4th model, something like **Employees**.

But I don't have any idea how to create a migration and define relationship between these models.

Comment: Role, in your example, doesn't seem like it'd require its own model, I'd define that as an attribute of the relationship between User and Company.

Comment: With a FK? Because I need to check what kind of Role the User is in that Company, there are some privileges for each role. 
Maybe my example for roles is not clear.

Comment: Yeah, if role has more associated with it then having it as a separate model might make sense.  If it's just a job title, then an attribute is sufficient.   In the case of a separate model, I would think role_id belongs on the company_users table / relationship since the role seems to be dependent on that relationship.

Answer (score 3):

I would also go for 4 tables as

- users
- roles
- companies
- user_role_company

First three tables will save the regular data without holding any foreign key from other tables, 4 table will related these tables to each other with following attributes

- user_id
- role_id
- company_id

Now your owing side tables which are users , roles and companies will define a relationship with user_role_company as `hasMany` and `user_role_company` will define inverse relation with these 3 tables as `belongsTo`

```
class User extends Model{

    public function userRoleCompany()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserRoleCompany', 'user_id','id');
    }

}

class Role extends Model{

    public function userRoleCompany()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserRoleCompany', 'role_id','id');
    }

}

class Company extends Model{

    public function userRoleCompany()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserRoleCompany', 'company_id','id');
    }

}


class UserRoleCompany extends Model{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'role_id');
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Erm, I am using Laravel 7, just out of curiosity, how do I retrieve, for instance, given User A, how do I find out the company he/she belongs and what role he/she plays? And if given user A and company B, can I find the role?

Comment: In first case query user model and load "userRoleCompany" using "with()" mehtod. For second example you can directly query 4th model UserRoleCompany and load "role" using "with()" method

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I'm in a similar situation as the question above

I have  3 models events,bands,artists that share one table

in this case when I want to know the bands linked to a specific event , I get a dupplicated band because it could be linked to  a different artist..
how can I get trhough this ?